# How to get an option for booting windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my Lenovo Ideapad laptop at the time of booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, lenovo

I had installed the ubuntu much earlier and I had been getting the option of booting either the windows 10 or ubuntu at the time booting starts. This happened automatically and I did not have to do anything additionally. But once while working with the windows I was showed the menu by the lenovo vantage to update the BIOS of the laptop. I did so successfully but now I could not get the option of switching between the ubuntu and windows 10 at the time of the start of booting. Therefore now I could not switch to my ubuntu OS and my laptop automatically opens the windows 10 OS without asking me my choice. Please help me get out of this problem?
Is the ubuntu software removed from the system?

Comment: I think you will need a live ubuntu installer USB(same one you used before) and reinstall grub.  Hopefully someone can give you instructions.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows